# why when i connect a table view cell to another view controller with modal segue i change things in the view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Sorry, I didn't know how to write the title right, so I will attack screenshots:

this is before i create the modal segue:

[image]

this is after i control drag from the cell to this view controller: (notice that the top bar with the save and cancel button disappeared)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Interface Builder, select the View Controller, change 'Inferred' under the Top Bar to 'Opaque Navigation Bar'.